# how to get common part of set of paths in xml file

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, path

I have an xml file which is transformed to a txt file, include only paths of nodes.
the txt file is like this:

```
root/book/author/infos/#text = Empire Burlesque
root/book/title/#text = XML Developer's 
root/book/genre/#text = Computer
root/book/price/#text = 44.95
root/book/publish_date/#text = 2000-10-01
root/book/description/#text = An in-depth look at creating applications 
root/book/author/infos/#text = Emhhsjshhh
root/book/title/#text = Midnight Rain
root/book/genre/#text = Fantasy
root/book/price/#text = 5.95
root/book/publish_date/#text = 2000-12-16
root/book/description/#text = A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
root/A1/A1A/#text = 1000
root/A1/A1B/#text = 2000
root/A1/A1C/#text = 3000
root/A2/A2A/#text = 4000
root/A2/A2B/#text = 5000
```

I want read the previous txt file and get another result like this, include only common paths:

```
root/book/
root/A1/
root/A2/
```

this is my Java code which browses the xml file and get paths of each node:

```
public void get_full_path_nodes(Document doc) throws XPathExpressionException, IOException {
        XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/root/descendant::node()");
        NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        // System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement());

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\dell  AC\\Desktop\\dataset\\all_paths.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nl.item(i);

            StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(node.getNodeName());
            String value = node.getTextContent();
            node = node.getParentNode();

            while (node.getNodeType() != Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
                path.insert(0, node.getNodeName() + '/');
                node = node.getParentNode();
                
            }

            out.println(path + " = " + value);               
        }
        out.close();    
  }  }
```

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: no there's no error , but i want a result with only commun part of paths : root/book/
root/A1/
root/A2/

Comment: Could you split on the `#` and just take `[0]`?

Comment: i think i should split by "/" and then comparing each path , and keeping only commun part of paths :/

Comment: So, you have a plan of attack. What have you tried?

Comment: not yet , i'm still drawing how to do it in paper :D , if i'll find a way , i'll share it here